# How to make Ubuntu honor "ignore-hosts" proxy settings for IPv6?

Tags: networking, proxy, ipv6

I just typed under `"dconf-editor", System → Proxy → ignore-hosts`, the following content:

```
['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8', '::1', '192.168.0.1', '2000::/3', 'fc00::/8']
```

But, Google Chrome (and `apt-get update / upgrade`) is just ignoring this settings.

EDITED: Also, Firefox doesn't honor the `ingore-hosts` settings, even configuring it to "Use system proxy settings".

For example, my Proxy Server (Ubuntu with Squid3) is in dual-stacked mode BUT, I do NOT want to access IPv6 web sites through the Proxy, that's why I'm trying to ignore the entire IPv6 Internet with the entry `2000::/3`, but, it does not work as expected.

EDITED: Also, I don't need the proxy to access `Hyperboria` sites, which resides under `fc00::/8` but, it doesn't work either...

### Why I'm doing this?

Because my environment is already a IPv6-Only Network and, to access the old internet infrastructure (IPv4-Only), I need to go through the dual-stacked proxy. But I need the proxy only when a web site doesn't have IPv6...

### How can I know that it doesn't work?!

It is simple, just access a web site that shows a IPv6 address on it, for example, `http://www.sixxs.net` or `http://ipv6.whatismyv6.com`, then, I'm still seeing the IPv6 address of the Proxy Server, so, `"ignore-hosts entry '2000::/3'"` doesn't seem to be working.

EDITED: Plus, when I'm trying to access a `Hyperboria` website, Squid returns an error that it can not reach `fc00::/8 network`

> (Squid ERROR: (101) Network is unreachable)

(of course it can't, the `cjdns` router is running right on my Ubuntu Desktop, so, no need to go through proxy when browsing `Hyperboria fc00::/8` but, Ubuntu isn't honoring `ignore-hosts` under proxy settings.

Comment: Some applications simply do not use this setting and send _all_ requests through the proxy if one is set.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this won't work with Gnome proxy settings. The `ignore-hosts` setting works for hostnames, addresses and address ranges, but apparently does not resolve hostnames before checking against addresses.

From [the `ignore-hosts` documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSimpleProxyResolver.html#GSimpleProxyResolver--ignore-hosts) (emphasis by me):

> Also note that hostname exclusions apply only to connections made to
>   hosts identified by name, and **IP address exclusions apply only to
>   connections made to hosts identified by address**. That is, if
>   example.com has an address of 192.168.1.1, and the :ignore-hosts list
>   contains only "192.168.1.1", then a connection to "example.com" (eg,
>   via a GNetworkAddress) will use the proxy, and a connection to
>   "192.168.1.1" (eg, via a GInetSocketAddress) will not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to *make* Ubuntu obey that setting, but there might be workarounds:

- APT follows  settings in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or the environment variables (such as `http_proxy`). The man pages for `apt.conf` don't mention dconf settings, so I think apt doesn't check them. To specify sites for which apt should ignore proxy, add to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

  ```
  Acquire::http::Proxy::<hostname/ip> DEFAULT;
  ```

  I think this can't be done for ranges or subnets, and you'll need an entry for each host to exclude.
- Chrome honours the no_proxy environment variable, so one might try using that:

  ```
  no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1,192.168.0.1,2000::/3,fc00::/8 google-chrome
  ```

  Define `no_proxy` in `/etc/environment` to ensure its availability everywhere. Other programs are known to honour this variable too.
- Lastly, you might consider running *two* squid servers. The new one will use your current one as a parent, but only for certain hosts, using the `allow_direct`/`never_direct` settings. Then set the new one as the proxy server everywhere (`/etc/apt/apt.conf`, `/etc/environment`, the `dconf` entries). I don't know much about dual stack networking, so I don't know if this would work, but it's worth a mention.

I don't use dual stack networking, but since I am behind a campus proxy, I have to juggle proxy settings, and I find that the last option is best. Let squid do the juggling.

Answer (score 1):

For Google Chrome and Chromium you can create a machine wide policy file.

[Linux Chrome Administrator Quick Start Guide](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start)

Here are various proxy settings and descriptions from the [Policy Template](http://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chrome/policy/policy_templates.zip):

```
// Proxy bypass rules
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Google Chrome will bypass any proxy for the list of hosts given here.  This
  // policy only takes effect if you have selected manual proxy settings at
  // 'Choose how to specify proxy server settings'.  You should leave this
  // policy not set if you have selected any other mode for setting proxy
  // policies.  For more detailed examples, visit:
  // http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings#TOC-
  // Command-line-options-for-proxy-sett

  //"ProxyBypassList": "http://www.example1.com,http://www.example2.com,http://internalsite/",

  // Choose how to specify proxy server settings
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Allows you to specify the proxy server used by Google Chrome and prevents
  // users from changing proxy settings.  If you choose to never use a proxy
  // server and always connect directly, all other options are ignored.  If you
  // choose to use system proxy settings or auto detect the proxy server, all
  // other options are ignored.  If you choose fixed server proxy mode, you can
  // specify further options in 'Address or URL of proxy server' and 'Comma-
  // separated list of proxy bypass rules'.  If you choose to use a .pac proxy
  // script, you must specify the URL to the script in 'URL to a proxy .pac
  // file'.  For detailed examples, visit: http://www.chromium.org/developers
  // /design-documents/network-settings#TOC-Command-line-options-for-proxy-sett
  // If you enable this setting, Google Chrome ignores all proxy-related options
  // specified from the command line.  Leaving this policy not set will allow
  // the users to choose the proxy settings on their own.

  //"ProxyMode": "direct",

  // URL to a proxy .pac file
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // You can specify a URL to a proxy .pac file here.  This policy only takes
  // effect if you have selected manual proxy settings at 'Choose how to specify
  // proxy server settings'.  You should leave this policy not set if you have
  // selected any other mode for setting proxy policies.  For detailed examples,
  // visit: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings
  // #TOC-Command-line-options-for-proxy-sett

  //"ProxyPacUrl": "http://internal.site/example.pac",

  // Address or URL of proxy server
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // You can specify the URL of the proxy server here.  This policy only takes
  // effect if you have selected manual proxy settings at 'Choose how to specify
  // proxy server settings'.  You should leave this policy not set if you have
  // selected any other mode for setting proxy policies.  For more options and
  // detailed examples, visit: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-
  // documents/network-settings#TOC-Command-line-options-for-proxy-sett

  //"ProxyServer": "123.123.123.123:8080",

  // Enable or disable PIN-less authentication
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // If this setting is enabled or not configured, then users can opt to pair
  // clients and hosts at connection time, eliminating the need to enter a PIN
  // every time.  If this setting is disabled, then this feature will not be
  // available.
```

Comment: Here's the Chromium command line docs, too: [Chromium Command Line Proxy Settings](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings)

Answer (score 0):

On GNOME Shell 42.3.1, for IPv4 and IPv6 I notice Firefox v107 ignore *Ignored hosts* (`gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy  ignore-hosts`; maybe due [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1582359)). I have to added again on Firefox on *No proxy for*:

[image: screenshot]