# How to add proxy exemption for a domain in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, proxy, npm

I have just appended this URL `https://registry.npmjs.org` into`no_proxy` in `etc\environment` file which I want to exempt from proxy restriction, it looks lie this.

```
no_proxy=localhost,https://registry.npmjs.org
```

But I am unable to contact the host even after the above setting has been made. Is there any additional changes to be done?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to setup the exemption:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts "['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8', '192.168.1.0/24', 'npmjs.org', '::1']"
```

To verify the settings enter this command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts
```

This should be the output:

```
['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8', '192.168.1.0/24', 'npmjs.org', '::1']
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but no luck

Comment: I changed the answer, please check it out. Set the /etc/environment to its default state, then use above commands.

Comment: Note that current [Firefox ignores that key](https://askubuntu.com/a/1442400/349837)